# Not able to catch user identity on windows 10 in vs2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, webforms

I'm trying to catch user identity but not able to catch it.
I turned windows features on or off and update Windows authentication,
but still not able to catch the login ID.
Any idea would be appreciated.

c# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string uid = "";

        try { uid = Session["uid"].ToString(); }
        catch { uid = ""; }

        if (uid == "" || uid == null)
        {
            uid = Page.User.Identity.Name;  
            if (uid.Length > 0)
            {
                uid = uid.Substring(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that you're using webforms instead of MVC. Also possibly you're missed some important settings, check out the Windows authentication requirements.

Comment: what does this ==>Page.User.Identity.Name return?

Comment: @PankajToshniwal Page.User.Identity.Name return null value